# How to modify HTML element instantly after it has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, greasemonkey

The `$(document).ready()` function is not very good if the page fails to load completely, or if it's loading very slowly.

How could I modify the element as soon as it has been created? Some delay is fine, as long as it's not multiple seconds.

I am using Greasemonkey also, if that matters. But I would be interested in a solution that works outside of Greasemonkey too.

I wouldn't want to break the performance on the webpage either.

**Edit:** I do not own the website I am modifying. Therefore I cannot put any code there manually.

I tried `window.onload = function(){}` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){})` but i noticed the jquery version was twice as fast.

Looks like people did not understand question before they downvoted.

Comment: Put the `<script>` block right after the element you want to modify.

Comment: Have you tried using setinterval to make a check if the element exists then set a user defined property to an element then create a user defined property for that certain element to be checked by the setinterval so that you will be able to kill the setinterval after the element to be modified has been loaded.

Comment: @Barmar, so how do i do that? The website is not mine.

Comment: @MikeAnte, you seem to be the only one who actually understood my question here. Is there any other way than checking by interval?

Comment: @Rookie Maybe if you could make a little map of what you are modifying. I will be able to provide a patch-up solution for you.

Comment: If you can't modify the document, how are you adding any Javascript to it?

Comment: @Barmar, Greasemonkey adds the JS on the page for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood your problem, so am rewriting my answer completely.

If `$(document).ready()` is too slow for you, then `onload` will definitely be too slow for you.  Without a snippet of code, I can't give you something specific, but this should work for you:

```
var checkIfExists = setInterval(function() {
    var exists = document.getElementById("foo");

    if (exists) {
        clearInterval(checkIfExists);
        doStuff(exists);
    }
}, 25);

function doStuff(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "bar";
}
```

Make sure ***not*** to put this inside of any `onload` or `ondomready` / `$(document).ready()` event handlers.

Once this script loads, it will check if an element with the `id` of `foo` exists every 25 milliseconds.  Once it can successfully find `foo`, it stops searching and runs function `doStuff`.  Now, I don't know if what you want to modify actually has an `id` or not, so you will have to figure out exactly how to search for it.

I'm sure you know this, but I wanted to mention that the number of times the interval runs is heavily dependent upon where the script is loaded in the html document.  For example, if it is at the bottom of the document it may only run once.  If it is in the header, it will run just until `foo` is loaded.

Here is a [working example with JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5L5s5xj/).

Comment: The website is not mine. I cant simply put something there by hands.

Comment: I tried `window.onload = function(){}` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){})` but i noticed the jquery version was twice as fast.

Comment: @Rookie I rewrote my answer to correctly address the problem.  Sorry I misunderstood it the first time.

Comment: Yeah i thought so. Maybe you can upvote my question then if you see it worthy. I will accept this / upvote since it seems to be only solution anyway.

Comment: @Rookie I already upvoted your answer earlier.  If you update the question, it will show up as active again and possibly get some more views.  Good luck :)